# Pipes between Python and C++ don't get closed

Tags: c++, python, pipe

I am spawning a process in python using subprocess and want to read output from the program using pipes. The C++ program does not seem to close the pipe though, even when explicitly telling it to close.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int fd = atoi(argv[1]);
  __gnu_cxx::stdio_filebuf<char> buffer(fd, std::ios::out);
  std::ostream stream(&buffer);
  stream << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  buffer.close();
  return 0;
}
```

I invoke this small program with this python snippet:

```
import os                                                                                         
import subprocess                                                                                 

read, write = os.pipe()                                                                           
proc = subprocess.Popen(["./dummy", str(write)])                                                  
data = os.fdopen(read, "r").read()                                                                
print data
```

The read() method does not return, as the fd is not closed. Opening and closing the write fd in python solves the problem. But it seems like a hack to me. Is there a way to close the fd in my C++ process?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spawning a child process on Linux (all POSIX OSes, really) is usually accomplished via `fork` and `exec`.  After `fork`, both processes have the file open.  The C++ process closes it, but the file remains open until the parent process closes the fd also.  This is normal for code using `fork`, and usually is handled by a wrapper around `fork`.  Read the `man` page for `pipe`.  I guess python has no way of knowing which files are being transferred to the child, though, and therefore doesn't know what to close in the parent vs the child process.

Comment: Interesting. Means that you close the file descriptor after the construction of the `Popen` object?

Comment: Please see also the example in the Python docs: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline . "The p1.stdout.close() call after starting the p2 is important in order for p1 to receive a SIGPIPE if p2 exits before p1." This means, yes, please close the handle in the Python process.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>POSIX file descriptors are local to the process. The file descriptor `write` from the Python tool is not valid in the C++ process.</strike>

Perhaps the easiest way would be to have the C++ process write its output to `stdout` (like `cout <<`), and Python call `Popen` using `stdout=PIPE` and read `proc.stdout` (or use `proc.communicate()` instead of using `fdopen`. This should work in Windows, too.

For passing the file descriptor as a command-line argument, see [Ben Voigt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320161/946850).

Comment: I don't remember what the conditions are, but it is possible to inherit file descriptors.